# why isn't the 'candidate' with most votes being printed?

Tags: c

```
bool print_winner(void)
{
    int others = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
       int h = others < candidate_count;
       
       if(candidates[i].votes > candidates[h].votes
       {
           printf("%s\n", candidates[i].name);
           return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
} ``
```

- `candidates` comes from this struct:

  ```
    typedef struct
    {
        string name;
        int votes;
        bool eliminated;
    }
  ```

  candidate;

what i want to do in the function is **print the name of the candidate with the most votes (the majority)**. however when i compile the program, *nothing would be printed.*
i have also created this function to 'eliminate' candidates, so it is possible that the error may be from there:

```
    void tabulate(void)
    {
        int others = 0;
    
            for(int i = 0; i<candidate_count; i++)
            {
              int h = others < candidate_count;
          
              if(candidates[i].votes < candidates[h].votes)
              {
                  //eliminate candidates[i].votes
                  candidates[i].eliminated = true;
              
              }
            } 
        return;
   }
```

***when i compile my program nothing seems to be wrong.**

Comment: It is not productive to try to debug or comment on incomplete code. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, how are we to verify that `candidate_count` is correct or whether any of the data is incorrectly constructed? Problem could be in any part of the code you have not shown.

Comment: `int h = others < candidate_count;` what do you intend that to do? `others < candidate_count` is a boolean expression. Why are you assigning a boolean expression to `h` and then using it as an array index? Furthermore, `others` never changes value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop on all candidates and keep the array index of the winner
For example

```
void print_winner(void)
{
    int winner = 0;
    if (!candidate_count)
        return;
    for (int i = 1; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {       
       if(candidates[i].votes > candidates[winner].votes) {
           winner = i;
       }
    }
    printf("The winner is %s\n", candidates[winner].name);
}
```

Comment: There may be a tied result.